# Find open Windows in XAML

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I need a functionality to get all existing (open) instances of some conrete `WPF` window. I create those windows programatically in few places in code.

Is there a XAML/WPF solution for that? Something like `GetInstancesByType(type)`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [Application.Windows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.windows.aspx) property:

```
foreach( var window in Application.Current.Windows.OfType<MyType>() )
{
    // do stuff
}
```

As H.B. pointed out, you would need to include `System.Linq` to get the `OfType<T>` extension method, but it's not necessary.

Comment: The question is not how to enumerate windows.

Comment: @H.B.: Umm... yes, it is.  The OP creates windows in code.  These windows are automatically added to the `Application.Windows` collection.  You can find them by name, `Type`, or whatever other property you wish to use.  What seems difficult to you about that?

Comment: The OP wants specific windows and asked for a XAML solution.

Comment: @H.B.: Ok, well good luck finding open windows in XAML.  I don't even know what you mean by "a XAML solution".  You could never do this in XAML.

Comment: You can do pretty much everything in XAML, [this extension](http://markupprogramming.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Getting%20Started&referringTitle=Home) being an extreme example.

Comment: Further there is no `OfType` method avaiable for the `WindowCollection` since it only implements the non-generic IEnumerable.

Comment: @H.B.: Hey, that's pretty cool! I didn't know that existed. I can't think of a good reason to use it in the vast majority of cases, but still cool nonetheless. That said, I don't think the OP wants a "XAML solution", I think he just associates XAML with WPF and used the terminology a bit incorrectly.

Comment: H.B.: You're wrong, try it out.  You just need to add the System.Linq namespace. that contains all of those extension methods.